# Prove the equation $AXB-BXA=0$ has at least one invertible solution in $M_n(F)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, matrix-equations

> Let $F$ be a field and $A,B \in M_n(F)$ (i.e., $A$ and $B$ are $n\times n$ matrices with entries in $F$).
> If there exist a linear combination of $A$ and $B$ which is invertible, then
> prove the equation $$AXB-BXA=0$$ has at least one invertible solution in $M_n(F)$.

**Attempt.**

If $A$ is invertible, then from $AXB=BXA$, we get $XBA^{-1}=A^{-1}BX$.  Then, we see that $X=A^{-1}$ is a solution.  Similarly, if $B$ is invertible, then $X=B^{-1}$ is a solution.

Comment: Of course, putting on hold this funny exercise  was absolutely necessary to ensure the survival of MSE...

Comment: @loupblanc I see merit in both removing this and keeping it. The fact that the assignment isn't as straight forward as most does not change the fact that it **is** a copy/pasted assignment without any context. But, whether it is "interesting" (or "funny" if you prefer) is in the eye of the beholder, and is difficult to decide objectively. We aren't drowned in questions like this, so I didn't vote, but... This discussion would IMHO be better in meta.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen , OK Jyrki, I understand.

Answer (score 5):

Assume that $\alpha A + \beta B$ is invertible. We claim that $X = (\alpha A + \beta B)^{-1}$ is the desired solution.

$\alpha$ and $\beta$ cannot both be $0$ so WLOG assume that $\alpha \ne 0$.

We have:

$$\alpha A(\alpha A + \beta B)^{-1}B + \beta B(\alpha A + \beta B)^{-1}B = (\alpha A + \beta B)(\alpha A + \beta B)^{-1}B = IB =B $$
$$\alpha B(\alpha A + \beta B)^{-1}A + \beta B(\alpha A + \beta B)^{-1}B = B(\alpha A + \beta B)^{-1}(\alpha A + \beta B) = BI =B $$

Subtracting these equalities gives:

$$\alpha A(\alpha A + \beta B)^{-1}B = \alpha B(\alpha A + \beta B)^{-1}A$$

Multiplication with $\frac1\alpha$ yields

$$AXB = BXA$$

Comment: +1: Nice. ${}{}$

Comment: How can you assure that there exists $\alpha,\beta$ such that $\alpha A+\beta B$ is invertible?

Comment: @GonzaloAlejandroBenavidesGa The question assumes there exists a linear combination of $A$ and $B$ which is invertible.

Comment: You're right. I didn't read carefully haha